# The problem of using the try exception dynamically

Tags: python, try-except

I have a function called `transform_exceptions()` that takes a list of functions, then calls each of the functions **(functions are without arguments)** and the exceptions that occur with the above convention to an object of `ExceptionProxy` and finally the list of transformed errors. It returns functions in the same order
Note: If a function is executed without error, an `ExceptionProxy` object should be created and its msg value should be `"ok!"` Slow quantification

smple:

```
class ExceptionProxy(Exception):
    # define your class here

def transform_exceptions(func_ls):
    # implement your function here

def f():
    1/0

def g():
    pass

tr_ls = transform_exceptions([f, g])

for tr in tr_ls:
    print("msg: " + tr.msg + "\nfunction name: " + tr.function.__name__)
```

Output:

```
msg: division by zero
function name: f
msg: ok!
function name: g
```

**my code :**

```
from mimetypes import init


class ExceptionProxy(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, function):
        self.msg = msg
        self.function = function


def transform_exceptions(func_ls):
    exception_list = []
    for func in func_ls:
        try:
            func
        except Exception as e:
            r = ExceptionProxy(str(e), func)
            exception_list.append(r)
        else:
            r = ExceptionProxy("ok!", func)
            exception_list.append(r)

    return exception_list
```

Comment: Re *"smple"*: Do you mean *"[simple](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/simple#Adjective)"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this when calling the function name in the list

```
func()
```

Also modified code:

```
class ExceptionProxy(Exception):
    def __init__(self,msg,function):
        self.msg = msg
        self.function = function


def transform_exceptions(func_ls):
    out = []
    for x in func_ls:
        try:
            x()
            a = ExceptionProxy("ok!", x)
        except Exception as e:
            a = ExceptionProxy(str(e), x)
        out.append(a)
    return out
```